# List filtering with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I came across this method in code:

```
private void FilterBasedUponPermission(List<Data.Indications.SpWeb_SavedIndications1LightDataObject> list)
        {
            list.RemoveAll(item =>
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_LLH && !isLLH) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_ALM && !isALM) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_RealEstate && !isRE) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_Auditor && !isAuditor));
        }
```

However, in the list passed in, some of the `permission` values are `null`, and it's keeping them in the filtered list. I want it to remove the items that also don't have a permission set, not just the ones that don't match the permission that you have as a user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a item.Permission == null

```
list.RemoveAll(item => item.Permission == null ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_LLH && !isLLH) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_ALM && !isALM) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_RealEstate && !isRE) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_Auditor && !isAuditor));
```

Comment: Thanks! LINQ is so easy but since I never use it simple things still confuse me =/

Answer (score 1):

Does on of those work?

```
list.RemoveAll(item => !item.Permission.HasValue); // in case Permission is Nullable<T>
list.RemoveAll(item => item.Permission == null);
```

You can add all the other conditions after a logical or (`||`).

Cheers,
Matthias

Comment: You realise your second line works for Nullables as well? So you don't need to treat them differently.

Comment: Also you appear to be doing the opposite of what was asked.

Comment: `list.RemoveAll(item => item.Permission != null);` will remove all valid list items. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I got it the wrong way. Corrected. Ray, that's true, I posted both ways so slandau can choose which one he prefers.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void FilterBasedUponPermission(List<Data.Indications.SpWeb_SavedIndications1LightDataObject> list)
        {
            list.RemoveAll(item =>
                (item.Permission == null) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_LLH && !isLLH) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_ALM && !isALM) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_RealEstate && !isRE) ||
                (item.Permission == Controllers.Indications.ICConstants.TradeType_Auditor && !isAuditor));
        }
```